# "Video or MIME format not supported" problem

Tags: windows, firefox, flash

In Firefox, a video file on a website that I want to watch opens up ... I can see about 2 seconds of the video and then I get the message "this is not available in your location"

In Tor, I get the "Video or MIME format not supported" message and I cannot see any video.

Firefox seems to be able to play the video but is unable to get around the location restriction. Whereas, Tor seems to be able to work around the location problem (which is why I tried using it), but then the format problem.

Is there any settings in Tor that I need to change or install some plug-in ?

Comment: Is it a Flash video? Flash is disabled by default in Tor Browser. Tools/Addons/Plugins The reason that it is disabled is because Flash can make its own connections that don't go through Tor, so that your real IP is known to the server that hosts the Flash video. If not, what is the URL of the movie in question?

Answer (score 1):

You can install flash (if it's a flash video) if you use Tails but that beats the purpose of using Tor but would be useful for your case if it is just to watch a video caused by a location restriction.

Comment: "You can install flash (if it's a flash video) if you use Tails but that beats the purpose of using Tor but would be useful for your case if it is just to watch a video caused by a location restriction." so are you saying that if I am using tails and I install flash I'll still be uncompromised?